# MKOverlayView and changing its alpha

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have a custom `MKOverlay` and `MKOverlayView`. When the `MKOverlayView` is created, I can set the `alpha` of the view:

```
-(void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    DatasetOverlay *datasetOverlay = (DatasetOverlay *)self.overlay;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:datasetOverlay.imageData];

    CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;

    MKMapRect theMapRect = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 1);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
}
```

But I want to be able to change the `alpha` of the view after its draw.

How can I do that?

I am have not worked much with Core Graphics yet.

Comment: Are you subclassing your MKOverlay? If so, how about [self setAlpha:.7];

Comment: MKOverlay does not have an alpha property.

Comment: But MKOverlayView does.

Comment: whoops yeah i meant MKOverlayView..my bad

Comment: Yep, it got me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    DLog(@"Fired");
    DatasetOverlay *datasetOverlay = (DatasetOverlay *)self.overlay;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:datasetOverlay.imageData];

    CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;

    MKMapRect theMapRect = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];



    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);
//    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 1);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
}
```

K, thanks to @ttarules's comment, I did some testing and realized I needed to remove the `CGContextSetAlpha()` and just set the `alpha` with the `MKOverlayView`'s alpha property. I can now change the `alpha` outside of initialization and give me what I need.